# How to do or do nothing base on AsyncTask result?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Experts,

My goal is simple, input an address, click a button to test a URL, if not get the expected result, a toast info and then do nothing. If get expect result, continue the program.

Since I can not use URL in UI thread, I used AsyncTask, the problem is: though I know the result from AsyncTak, how to inform activity to do or do nothing?
What I want is a statement inside the OnClickListener like this:

```
if (result is not expected) return; else continue do things.
```

I cannot write above statement in onPostExecute, it will return onPostExecute(), not onClickLIstener().

Another is: even if I can pass the result to activity(namely to onClickLIstener()), when the result arrives, probably UI thread already run some other codes, but they shouldn't before knowing the result.

In short, I need the URL result to decide how to run remaining codes, therefore cannot use async task, what should I do?

Thanks.

Below is the example code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        new XXX().execute(code);
 });

}


 class XXX extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... strArr) {
        XXXXX;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        XXXXX;
    }
}
```

Comment: well network tasks should be done asynchronously anyway, you can make sure that nothing else is happening on the MainUI by using some sort of indeterminate progress bar. Set it to Visible when you start the asynctask and then set it to invisible `onPostExecute()` and do the rest of the things you have to do.

Comment: sounds good, could you tell me more detail please? Beside, what is the most regular way for such task: base on URL result to do or do nothing in activity. ?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing. If you have something that requires a constant connection to a server you would probably use a Thread that runs continuously and then contacts the MainUI using a Handler. If its something thats one time, like a button click and then something happens, then the asynctask is a good way to go. 

If you look at Eenvincible's answer below, you just call that function in `onPostExecute()` and put whatever you need to do in that function. If you need some sort of result then add arguments to the function e.g. `private void executeOnAsyncSuccess(String result)`

Comment: also in the function `private void executeOnAsyncSuccess(String result)` you can do something like 
`if(result==bad){//do nothing}else{//Do something}
`

Comment: nice, learn a lot! Thanks a lot! Do the rest codes in onPostExecute also solves the async problem.

Comment: So anything in `onPostExecute` runs in the UI Thread. Whatever network stuff you need to do you put inside `doInBackground()`. That takes care of the Async stuff. Then you return your result from `doInBackground()` which goes to `onPostExecute`. So you can do your UI stuff in `onPostExecute` or put the stuff in a function and call that function from `onPostExecute` like the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy. Try this approach:

Since you already have your AsyncTask as an inner class in your activity, you can easily return a result in `onPostExecute()` then check if request was successful or not.

Now, here is the final part: create a method in your activity like this:

```
private void executeOnAsyncSuccess(){
   //place the code here you want to run
}
```

Now you can call it inside `onPostExecute()` easily!

You can also do this using `Events` but this approach should just work!

I hope this helps!

Comment: sorry I cannot follow. Are you saying execute executeOnAsyncSuccess() inside the onPostExecute() when result is expected? But result is just the beginning, I have many other method, inner classes, put all of them inside executeOnAsyncSuccess() ? I am not sure. What I more like is a way to get the result in OnClickListener() rather than onPostExecute()

Comment: If you are inside onPostExecute(), use an if statement to know if the result is successful and if so, call the executeOnAsyncSuccess method - then you inside that method, do whatever you would have done inside onClickListener

Comment: ok, now doInBackground() gives true or false to onPostExecute(), but how about variables in UI thread(OnClickListener)?  For example, String code =xxxx; in UI thread. Now I am in onPostExecute(), how to use code?

Comment: onPostExecute runs on your UI thread meaning you can access your class variables from there;

Comment: right, I convert all the necessary variables from local to class level. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I just learned that maybe Callable is a good way, use its V get().